# What does !important mean in vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js

What does `!important` mean in VueJS?

I am new to vue.js and I am seeing this piece of code included after values in style sheets.
I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of a duplicate. I thought it was a vue.js thing, so I didn't look under css. my bad.

Answer (score 2):

`!important` is used in CSS to make sure that style overrides any competing styles.

lets say I have a button `.btn` and it was in a container called `.btn-container`

if I had css this css

```
.btn {
 color: red !important;
}

.btn-container .btn {
  color: blue;
}
```

the `.btn` color would still be red even though the nested rule is higher in specificity. Once you add the !important it overrides the specificity. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception